# Is there a python function similar to sklearn.PolynomialFeatures but for strings?

Tags: python, string, scikit-learn, polynomials

The `sklearn.PolynomialFeatures` function generates the polynomial and interaction features of a vector. For example :

```
>>> X = [[1,2,3]]
>>> G = sklearn.PolynomialFeatures(degree = 3, interaction_only = True, bias = False)
>>> G.fit_transform(X)
>>> print(G)
>>>
array([[1., 2., 3., 2., 3., 6., 6.]])
```

Is there an equivalent function that could work for strings so that if the input array is 
`X = [['a','b','c']]` the function would output `array([['a','b','c','ab','ac','bc','abc']])`
and that the function could take any input vector ? 
If no such function exist, do you have an idea on how to create it ?

Comment: so basically you're just looking to find all permutations of a list of strings?

Comment: No, more like combinations since 'ab' and 'ba' are basically the same interactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the [superset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of the input list of strings. This is fairly easy to implement using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), though if you want to have the `fit`/`transform` structure (allowing you to include the transformer in a pipeline), you can define your own transformer inheriting from `TransformerMixin`. Otherwise just use the code contained in the `transform` method:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from itertools import combinations, chain

class NSuperset(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def fit(self, X):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        superset = [[''.join(c) for x in X for c in combinations(x, r=i)] 
                    for i in range(1,self.n+1)]
        return list(chain.from_iterable(superset))
```

---

```
ss = NSuperset(n=3)

X = [['a','b','c']]
ss.fit_transform(X)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc']
```